# Configuring webapp.runner to accept https and http traffic in dev environment

Tags: tomcat, heroku, https

I have a heroku project, and I am successfully using https in my production environment.  I am not sure how to configure webapp.runner (embedded tomcat) to accept connections on both http and https in my dev environment.  Is there a configuration for this?  Or should I grab the source files and edit the code?  Right now I am toggling all of the https domains to http in my dev environment, but that is not ideal, and I can't see if https functionality is working without deploying to heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lack of other responses, I try to answer this but I am not a Heroku user.

I think it depends on how you install/launch webapp.runner .

Tomcat can be configured for this. Search for the file "server.xml" which contains Tomcat service definition. Look for the following piece:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

In order to enable HTTPS, you need to change it following the guidelines at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html .

However, note that under Heroku HTTPS  shall be handled by the balancer as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing, and I think your application is actually accessed via HTTP . In other words, your application in Heroku would not receive HTTPS traffic.

Comment: you are correct that the application doesn't actually receive http traffic.  but some of the urls in my app still use https protocol.  i just want to know the right way to deal with the dev environment for a webapp runner/heroku application.  in webapp runner the embedded tomcat is configured inside a java class, which is built into a jar file.  it seems like the only way to deal with this is to get the source files, edit them, and rebuild the jar.  thanks for your response.

Comment: Ok, but I reckon you should be avoiding this problem in the first place. It's *very* recommended to avoid using absolute URLs in any case. Using Struts or Spring MVC makes it really easy, but whatever the framework you use, the request URI information is always available in the HttpServletRequest (this is, as long as you don't need to access the SSL session details from your app).

Comment: This is my first foray into implementing SSL requirements.  The best practice is to do a server side redirect?  I assumed that you would verify on the server that the connection is ssl.  I'm using struts 2, I guess there is a plugin I should look at.

Comment: I don't think redirects are involved. Using Struts2, you can use the `<s:url>` tag [like in these examples](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-url-tag-example/) and other means to ensure that you always generate URLs that correspond to the URI used by the client. This way, no matter how users access the application (including schema: http or https), you are generating valid URLs for them, and also in development environments. JSTL also has tags to generate valid URLs.

Comment: Yes, SSL is normally handled externally (by the HTTP  balancer, or a different web server fronting the Java application server). If I understand correctly, there's no need of a Struts2 plugin whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "manually" configure SSL on Heroku, you need to get Heroku's SSL Endpoint Add-On: https://addons.heroku.com/ssl

This article explains the installation process in detail, it's pretty easy to setup: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

---

### Updated to better answer poster's question

This is how to run your app locally using maven's jetty plugin:

Step 1: Add this to your pom.xml under your development profile:

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
      <configuration>
         <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
         </webAppConfig>
         <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
               <port>8080</port>
               <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
               <port>8443</port>
               <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
               <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
               <password>jetty6</password>
               <keyPassword>jetty6</keyPassword>
            </connector>
         </connectors>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>clean</id>
            <goals>
               <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
         <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>genkey</id>
            <goals>
               <goal>genkey</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
         <keystore>${project.build.directory}/jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
         <dname>cn=localhost</dname>
         <keypass>jetty6</keypass>
         <storepass>jetty6</storepass>
         <alias>jetty6</alias>
         <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Step 2: run the app

```
mvn clean jetty:run -Pdevelopment
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at this.  i edited the question to try to clarify that the issue is in dev mode rather than in production.

Comment: @rquinn - No problem, check out updated answer. Hope it helps.